# Configuring modules in ZendFramework

Tags: zend-framework, module

I have a problem using modules in ZendFramewok. I have so far created the directory sturucture for modules in application directory.

Application
--configs
--Bootstrap.php
--modules
----default
------controllers
--------ErrorController.php
--------IndexController.php
------models
------views
--------helpers
--------scripts
----------error
------------error.phtml
----------index
------------index.phtml

```
Updated application.ini by adding the following lines:
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION "/modules"
resources.module[] = ""
```

Setup Virtual host for public as ServerName.local

So if type in browser Servername.local I get the default view, but if I type Servername.local/:default/:index/:index I get a 403(Forbidden), if I type Servername.local/default/index/index I get a 404(Not Found), any help??

Comment: Do you have a route to the modules?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your missing an "s" on `resources.module[]`, might want to update that to:

```
resources.modules[] = ''
```

Comment: Probably just a typo in the question, we'd have an fatal error if that was the case.

Comment: modules resource totally unrelated to this problem as it used to bootstrap module bootstraps. And he haven't any. So this resource does nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if mod_rewrite enabled and configured in .htaccess. I believe this 404 error coming from server and not from your application.

After that check your index controller defined as followed: `Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action`

If this is not your issue i'll throw in more suggestions.